# Writing the data in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am inserting huge amount of data on to mongodb using node.js. The program is working fine and i can see in the database path of mongo db the data are written as files which is of databasename.0 which is 128 kb, databasename.1 which is 256 kb, databasename.0 which is 512 kb,databasename.0 which is 1024 kb, and last file of 2048 kb while inserting the last file which is of 2048 kb the connection is lost with mongodb and the data is not inserted. Why is this happening how to get rid of this please explain me the concept. I will attach the code which am using to insert the data.
// connection.js which is used to establish the connection

```
var Db = require('mongodb').Db;
var connection = require('mongodb').connection;
var Server = require('mongodb').Server;
var connectionInstance;
module.exports = function(callback) {
    if (connectionInstance) {

        callback(connectionInstance);
        return;
    }
    var serverOptions = {
        'auto_reconnect': true,
        'poolSize': 100
    };
    var db = new Db('test', new Server('localhost', 27017, serverOptions));
    db.open(function(err, databaseconnection) {

        if (err)
            console.log(err);
        connectionInstance = databaseconnection;
        console.log("connection Established");
        callback(databaseconnection);
    });
};

//The pgm to insert the data on to the mongodb using node.js
var i = 0;
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var mongoServer = require('mongodb').Server;
var serverOptions = {
    'auto_reconnect': true,
    'poolSize': 5
};
var i = 0;
var async = require('async');
var mongoClient = new MongoClient(new mongoServer('localhost', 27017, serverOptions));
var db = mongoClient.db('test');
var collection = db.collection('new_file_test');
var doc
mongoClient.open(function(err, mongoClient) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    };

    function save(callback) {
        console.log("Am the first");
        doc = {
            'trip_paramid': "111",
            'tripid': '116',
            'lattitude': '12.8929183',
            'longitude': '77.63627',
            'speed': '2',
            'heading': '0',
            'altitude': '80469',
            'address': 'qwertyasdfgxcvbn',
            'engine_status': 'Normal',
            'oil_pressure': '83.12',
            'water_temp': '28',
            'fuel_content': '0',
            'brake': 'Normal',
            'creation_time': '2013-08-31 23:22:17',
            'brakelight_status': 'Normal',
            'battery_status': '12.68',
            'event_code': '8',
            'dbinsert_time': '2013-08-31 23:24:59',
            'gsm_status': '-51',
            'cell_id': '45',
            'vehicle_id': '123456',
            'distance': '0'
        }
        callback(doc);
    }
    save(function(doc) {
        console.log("I got it first");
        console.log("Inserting" + i);
        collection.insert(doc, function(err) {
            if (err)
                console.log('Error occured');
            else
                console.log("Inserted" + i);
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to better format the code?

Comment: Did that for him...When I was here for the first time I didn't know how to format it, either ;)

Comment: rather than your code, what is needed to diagnose this is why "the connection is lost with mongodb and the data is not inserted" in particular, what is the error?   Is there an error on mongod side (look in logs), is there an error in your app (log or print it and include it here).

Comment: The error thrown in database: Sat May 17 08:44:02.922 Socket say send() errno:10054 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. 127.0.0.1:270
17
Sat May 17 08:44:03.016 Error: socket exception [SEND_ERROR] for 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/query.js:78
Sat May 17 08:44:03.016 trying reconnect to 127.0.0.1:27017
Sat May 17 08:44:03.952 reconnect 127.0.0.1:27017 failed couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017

Comment: The error while tried to run the program again:        collection = dbconnection.collection('new_file_test');
                                  ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'collection' of null
    at docs (C:\Documents and Settings\sabarish.radhakrishn\Desktop\from.js:24:28)
    at C:\Documents and Settings\sabarish.radhakrishn\Desktop\connection.js:24:6

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the 32 bit mongodb am using with which can store only data of around 2GB. When i replaced it with 64 bit it works perfect.